# How do I switch the page displayed in a Shiny DataTable?

Tags: r, pagination, shiny, user-input, dt

I can change the page initially shown in a DataTable using the callback parameter e.g. `output$testTable <- DT::renderDataTable(iris, callback = JS('table.page(2).draw(false);'))`
But how do I change the page in response to user input? Is there something analogous to `selectRows` using a `dataTableProxy`?

Comment: It can be done using javascript. This example simply uses javascript to send info from server to js info message, but you can do more interesting things by writing a different js function on the UI end, see: http://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/server-to-client-custom-messages.html

Answer (score 3):

Here is how to do it. You need to create a custom js function and then call it from the server like so (in this example the button changes the page to a random page):

```
library(shiny) 
library(DT)

shinyApp( 
  ui = fluidPage(
    mainPanel(DT::dataTableOutput("test"),
              actionButton("btn","Press me"),
              tags$script(HTML(
    "Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler('pager',function(page) {
      $('#'+'test').find('table').DataTable().page(page).draw(false);
    })"
                )))), 
  server = function(input, output,session) { 


    output$test <- DT::renderDataTable({
     mtcars

    })
    observeEvent(input$btn,{

      page <- sample(1:4,1)

      session$sendCustomMessage("pager",page-1)

    })    
  }
)
```